# PHP: Why is there 2 '->' in this code?

Tags: php, drupal-7

This code is from Drupal 7 php and is as follows:

```
if (!empty($data->_field_data['nid']['entity']->field_inst_address['und'][0]['administrative_area'])) {
      echo $data->_field_data['nid']['entity']->field_inst_address['und'][0]['administrative_area'];
} else echo " ";
```

I"m confused about this:

There is 2 **->** signs. From my understanding, when you have a array, you can use key-value pairs and the => sign would separate them. The same is true for objects.

But why does this code have 2 on the same line, rather than just 1? Is this a multi-dimensional array thing going on? Can someone explain it please? Thank you.

Comment: I can't see => only -> in your code

Comment: Oh crap, your right. Sorry, I meant -> and not =>

Comment: The `->` means that the item on the left hand side is an object, and the right hand side is a property. If you get more than one on the same line, it means that a property is also an object with its own properties (or it contains an object).